# "Yonder" as a fabric or fiber

Tags: meaning

In the novel *Fortress of Eagles* by C.J. Cherryh, the word "yonder" is used  like this:

> ... the most incorruptible, tiresome priest alive, ... him in the rope belt and rough-spun yonder.

Although it is a fantasy novel, all of the materials and species it references are ones found in real life, and it doesn't [use made up names to refer to real life things](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/CallARabbitASmeerp), so my guess is that this is some very archaic usage of the word "yonder".  However, none of my googling has found anything about the word ever naming a type of fabric or fiber.

Comment: I'm thinking I've seen a garment with a similar name.

Comment: @HotLicks Yonder-wear?

Comment: The *OED* print versions are unaware of *yonder* as a name for a fiber.  Are you sure the sentence doesn't mean "him, the one over there wearing a rope belt and homemade clothes"?

Comment: **Context matters.** People avoid him: "even His Holiness avoided his company, Efanor'spriest, Jormys, him in the rope belt and rough-spun yonder." He's standing alone *over there (yonder)* in his humble clothing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Yonder* is being used here in its normal sense to mean *over there*.

I think what's confusing you is the term 'rough-spun' - it's being used as a noun, not an adjective, and means 'cloak' or 'priest's habit' in this context.

Comment: This site defines it as a noun: https://www.wordnik.com/words/roughspun

Comment: Ah, I had no idea "rough-spun" could be a noun.

Comment: Yeah, the hyphens might throw you off.

Answer (score 0):

There's no definition in the *Oxford English Dictionary* that indicates such a usage or meaning for *yonder*. So the most straightforward way to interpret it is as an adverb. *Rough-spun* could be a noun.

It *could* also be a pun, given the beginning of the next paraphragh (*over there in that **knot** of gossipers*) and its use of ***wonder***, but I'm not sure we can credit such ingenuity to this author. On the other hand maybe so...

> Now perhaps they were saying, over there in that knot of gossipers, the wonder of it! the holy Jormys had converted a Sihhe-lord… when he knew damned well Jormys had been afraid to go into that room and only Efanor had gone